# Print quality on magnetic roll vinyl

Tags: print-design, pdf, image-quality, color-profile, print-production

I have a project which required printing on magnetic vinyl. I received a sample from the printer and the quality is awful, pixelated and grainy (see attached sample). The printer is usually excellent, but they cannot figure out the problem, and the manufacturer is unhelpful. Can anyone shine a light on how I can get better print quality? Printing from a PDF X1a file, with high res images and vector artwork.

[image: Original sample profile photo]

[image: printed on magnetic roll - pixelated]

Edit: 600dpi tiff conversion solves the issue. Here is a sample of the reprint with proper quality;

[image: text area]
[image: image area]

Comment: you can export the file in tiff format with a dpi of more than 600

Comment: I'll try that and post if print quality improves

Comment: atet's solution solved the problem. Can You edit your comment as an answer? I'll post a photo of the improved print too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the file in tiff format with a dpi of more than 600

Comment: Worked a charm (can't post image in comments)

Comment: post in the question and mention below the final result

Answer (score 3):

You can not do anything.

Some printers simply have a low DPI. Dots per inch... in this case the droplet of ink is simply big. They are probably using a different printer than the one you are used to, probably because of the width of the magnet.

One thing you can do is print on adhesive normal vinyl, that is thiner, and paste it on a blank magnet.

Comment: Yes that is the printer's solution too. Their printer is 1440dpi which you would think would be enough. The final product needs to be cut into many pieces so I just hope the adhesive vinyl gives a neat finish. thanks

Comment: When you paste the adhesive vinil make sure it is pressed, normally with a ink roller: https://www.google.com/search?q=ink+roller. The pasted vinyl could shrink a bit in time if you have some temperure issues, like too hot lights on it, but probably nothing important, depending on the size of each pice. Make some tests.

Comment: 1440 yeap, that will do.